# Override __str__ of parent class

Tags: python, class, overriding

I have a problem and I can't seem to find a solution. I have 3 classes `A`, `B` and `C`, with `A` being the superclass.

```
class A(object):
    def __str__(self):
        self._general_representation(str)

    def _general_representation(self,to_string):
        (nominal_value, std_dev) = (self._nominal_value, self.std_dev())

    def std_dev(self)
        a = error_components()*something

    def error_components(self):
        return something

class B(A):


class C(B):
```

I want class `C` to be able to override the `std_dev()` and `error_components()` of the 'grandparent' class. How can I do this? I can't change class A and B. Is there a way to this in python 3.3?

Comment: Do you have a basic understanding of OO programming?

Comment: I'm learning now but not starting from basics. Deadlines...

Comment: I've edited your psuedo-code to be closer to actual python, but there are most likely still errors in it; `std_dev` doesn't return a value, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define them on class C. The functions are looked up on `self`, not on the class the calling method is defined in.

```
class C(B):
    def std_dev(self)
        return self.error_components() * something + something_else_again

    def error_components(self):
        return something_entirely_different
```

Comment: @humberto: Then you need to provide *much more* detail about the base classes. They may not be doing what you think they are doing. For the example you cobbled together, my answer would work.

Comment: It worked on python 2.7 but i had to move to pyhton 3.3. Since then doesn't seem to work. Class A,B are in a diferent module, does that make a difference?

Comment: @humberto: no, it doesn't. I think something *else* stopped working when you switched to Python 3.3.

Comment: I got it, the variable I want to print doesn't belong anymore to the class C, but to class A...starting to hate python lol